# Trouble Code decoding

Tags: chevrolet, obd-ii, silverado, dtc

I've got a trouble code in my car and unable to figure how to decode it.

```
008
0: 43 03 00 59 01 54 
43 00 
1: 01 55 AA AA AA AA AA
```

I can understand the response is in multiple frames, but unable to decode the same. Also, figuring out what this 008 in the beginning is.Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you pulling this data? Where in the protocol does this fragment appear?

Answer (score 2):

Your framing format looks odd, but anyways. This is the answer to `03`, which is querying the diagnostic trouble codes. Stripped from the multi framing, your result is actually

```
03 00 59 01 54 01 55
```

which means: You have three DTC, which are to be decoded as written in the SAE standards. The results boil down to

```
P0059 => Powertrain > SAE defined > undefined
P0154 => Powertrain > SAE defined > fuel and air metering
P0155 => Powertrain > SAE defined > fuel and air metering
```